# Calling Python from C: ./a.out: /lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_7.0.0' not found (required by ./a.out)

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api

I'm able to compile and link my program successfully, but running the `a.out` file results in:

```
./a.out: /lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_7.0.0' not found (required by ./a.out)
```

The output of `ls /lib | grep libgcc` is:

```
libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1
```

My GCC is version 4.8.5. Is there some step I'm missing to force it to use libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1 ?

I'm able to compile and run Python C Extensions built with `python setup.py install`, so I know that my GCC version should be able to do this. However, now I'm trying to build a C application that can run Python which is giving this error.

---

I have a trivial file, `c.c`:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    printf("hello\n");
    return 1;
}
```

~/apps/miniconda3/bin/python3-config --cflags results in the following:

```
-I/apps/miniconda3/include/python3.7m -I/apps/miniconda3/include/python3.7m  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -march=prescott -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O3 -pipe  -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -fuse-linker-plugin -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -flto -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall
```

~/apps/miniconda3/bin/python3-config --ldflags results in the following:

```
-L/apps/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-i386-linux-gnu -L/apps/miniconda3/lib -lpython3.7m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lrt -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic
```

I am compiling like this:

```
gcc -c $(~/apps/miniconda3/bin/python3-config --cflags) -m32 c.c
```

I am linking liks this:

```
gcc c.o $(~/apps/miniconda3/bin/python3-config --ldflags) -m32
```

Both of these commands work without error or warning, and result in a `a.out` executable.

However, running this executable gives the error message:

```
./a.out: /lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_7.0.0' not found (required by ./a.out)
```

Comment: Just a guess looking over this: Does miniconda ship with a version of `libgcc_s`?

Comment: @jordanm in the miniconda3/lib directory I see a `libgcc_s.so` and `libgcc_s.so.1`. Likewise in the miniconda3/pkgs/ directory I see a few like `libgcc-ng-8.2.0-h9268252_1/lib/libgcc_s.so`

Comment: Does a.out work if you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the miniconda3/lib directory when you run a.out?

Comment: @jordanm yes it works! Please add this as an answer, and if you don't mind, could you explain why? Perhaps when I run my Python C extensions via Python, Python automatically adds this to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but if I'm running C code that calls Python, I have to do it manually.

Comment: I'm not a C developer so my explanation would likely be wrong. I was just guessing based on my experience of compiling other people's code over the years. I will leave the answer open for someone who actually knows what is going on here :)

Comment: @jordanm Ok. Would you have any idea if it's possible to do this without setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH? I assume not, but I'm on a shared environment and wouldn't want to cause any conflicts by mucking around with the LD_LIBRARY_PATH which is also used by a large legacy application. Thanks so much.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen You can use the 'rpath' argument when you compile with GCC to set a program-specific "runtime library-specific search path". Try Google for some examples. Note that 'rpath' is actually a linker option that's passed through GCC.

Comment: @David Thanks! I just noticed that when I compile the Python C Extension, python seems to be adding that. Tacking on -Wl,-rpath=~/apps/miniconda3/lib to the linker arguments works.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen That's exactly what you want, yes.

Comment: @jordanm since no one has wrote an answer, would you please do so?